# How to hide labels in ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, labeling, dynamic-layer

Does anyone know how I would go about hiding labels in a  ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer?

This is part of my code so far:

```js
var routeLayer = ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(...);
map.addLayer(routeLayer);
var drawingOptions = new LayerDrawingOptions();
drawingOptions.showLabels = false;
var options = [];
options[0] = drawingOptions;
routeLayer.setLayerDrawingOptions(options);
```

After doing this however the layer isn't shown on the map.

Do I need to set the renderer property for drawingOptions as well?

Comment: There's an Esri sample [Change attribute used for a renderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/renderer_dynamic_layer_change_attribute.html) which uses `setLayerDrawingOptions` - can you try the same syntax in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this is how i solved it.

I added a renderer to drawingOptions

```
var sls = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, esri.Color([255, 255, 0]), 3);
drawingOptions.renderer = SimpleRenderer(sls);
```

After i did that i had to enable dynamic workspaces in the service capabilities via the server manager.

Hope this helps someone.